# Schema modelling with functions

Tags: function, functional-programming, schema, data-modeling, first-class-functions

I am looking for a schema language that allows definition of functions. I thought of http://json-schema.org/ at first, but that format is data-only. My knowledge from XSD is the same.

The language is at first not important, my project is just starting, so there is plenty of flexibility. The thing which, i think, is important, is to be able to model a datastructure containing functions.

Ultimately it is possible to model a function with the data-only literals, which will be my last resort if no good language with native support exists.

Comment: UML if diffenately nice when designing software projects etc.  But to my knowledge it cannot be used for typechecking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I function i something that is solely manifested in a core language. This means that it generally can not be serialized.

The solution is, as mentioned, to model functions. This is done by modelling application and abstraction (lambda functions).